# Is it possible to use a link on a website to change browser tabs?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to have a button/link that opens google in a new tab, but if that tab is already open then just focus that tab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Kind of.** The closest thing I can think of would be something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="example">Link</a>
```

When you click it the first time, it will open the link in a new tab. Subsequent clicks of the link will navigate the tab it opened the first time (even if that tab has since navigated to a different page). It will not change the page of a tab that was opened without using the link.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

you can focus a window that you've opened with window.open and have a reference to with `window.focus` ( [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.focus) ), sometimes.

You might be able to do this with a browser plugin, depending on the browser.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can and it is quite simple task** - but remember that nowadays some browsers (With addons) will either block a new window you create or will not recognize it as "pop-up" that can be controled in some internal JavaScript.

Proper method is:

```
<script>
var myTab;

function openIt()
{
myTab=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
myTab.document.write("<p>Some kind of inner text</p>");
myTab.blur(); // this will un-activate opened window/tab
}

function activateIt()
{
myTab.focus();
}
</script>


<input type="button" value="Open" onclick="openIt()">
<input type="button" value="Activate" onclick="activateIt()" />
```

To controll it see documentation for window.open() method.

Comment: you can't focus the tab if you do not have handler for it. You must know tab's object (think of it as "name" or "id") to refer to it. To know this object name you have to create it. Simple target="_blank" will not work in that case - you can't refer to that tab.

Comment: Right, so why does your answer not address this whatsoever?